Add an MBtiles with Vector Tiles to GeoServer through Python
I have an MBTiles file that contains vectors. I'm attempting to upload it to a remote GeoServer, but running into issues. The file will upload to the geoserver but with errors and I cannot create a layer from the coverage store. I've been able to upload it manually and that works. I've tampered with the code below several times with no luck. What am I missing here?
store_url = f"{geoserver_url}/workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores"
payload = {
    "coverageStore": {
        "name": store_name,
        "workspace": workspace,
        "type": "MBTiles with vector tiles",
        "url": f"file:{mbtiles_fp}"  # Update with your directory path
    }
}


# Set up the URL for creating a layer
layer_url = f"{geoserver_url}/workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores/{store_name}/coverages"


auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
auth_response = requests.get(geoserver_url, auth=auth)

if auth_response.status_code == 200:
    print("Authentication successful!")

    # Create the GeoTIFF store
    store_response = requests.post(store_url, auth=auth, json=payload)


What are the errors?

"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Could not find the raster plugin for format MBTiles with vector tiles"
I think it has something to do with
"type":"MBTiles with vector tiles" in the payload in the code. However if I change it to just MBTiles, it tries uploading it as a raster MBTiles
